# Fred's Imagemagick Script

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am unable to use **fred's imagemagick script** on my shared linux hosting. Currently I am using fisheye script. It runs perfectly but showing me an error:

> "FILE **filename** DOES NOT EXIST OR IS NOT AN ORDINARY FILE, NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO SIZE".

I think the *convert* command in fisheye script is not found as i saved the script somewhere in my folder(eg. `'demo/imscript/fisheye'`) but *convert* is not in this folder. *convert* command is in `'usr/local/bin'`.

Comment: The errors are not coming now.I change convert -> /usr/local/bin/convert in fisheye script.But conversion is not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely that the ImageMagick script does not have access to your server's temp directory.

You need to edit the script and explicitly set you temp directory

For more info, take a look at the following answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28302265/1012699